# Simplepie shows php code

Tags: simplepie

I am using SimplePie for Yahoo weather forecast. I am on a new Server and now the output looks like this:

```
set_feed_url($path . $code); $feed->set_item_class('SimplePie_Item_YWeather'); $feed->init(); function time2minuts($time) { $minuts = 0; $atime = explode(" ", $time); $ttime = explode(":", $atime[0]); if ($atime[1] == "pm") { if ((int)$ttime[0]!=12) $ttime[0] = $ttime[0] + 12; } $minuts = (int)$ttime[0] * 60 + (int)$ttime[1]; return $minuts; } $weather = $feed->get_item(0); $fore = $weather->get_forecasts(); $unit = $weather->get_units_temp(); $ampm = "n"; // indica noche $icon = $weather->get_condition_code(); // Calculamos la hora de Mallorca en minutos $curday = time2minuts(date("g:i a")); //echo $curday.'---'.date('h:m d.m.y').'---'.date("g:i a"); $iniday = time2minuts($weather->get_sunrise()); $endday = time2minuts($weather->get_sunset()); if ($curday > $iniday && $curday < $endday) { $ampm = "d"; // indica dia } $land = $weather->get_country(); if($land == 'Spain') { $land = 'Spanien'; } ?>
```

This is my php code. My PHP Version is 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.6 simplepie 1.3.1

Thank you for your help,

mallmis

Comment: Did you mean for everything to be on one line?

Comment: It looks like there is a syntax error in your PHP file. Can you show us the PHP source code?

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your fast response.

My script is working ón the old server. But I will post:

```
    <?
require("simplepie.inc");
require("simplepie_yahoo_weather.inc");

$code = "769293"; // Menorca 12517557
$path = "http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?u=c&w=";


$feed = new SimplePie();
$feed->set_feed_url($path . $code);
$feed->set_item_class('SimplePie_Item_YWeather');
$feed->init();


function time2minuts($time)
{
$minuts = 0;
$atime = explode(" ", $time);
$ttime = explode(":", $atime[0]);
if ($atime[1] == "pm") {
if ((int)$ttime[0]!=12) $ttime[0] = $ttime[0] + 12;
}
$minuts = (int)$ttime[0] * 60 + (int)$ttime[1];
return $minuts;
} 

$weather = $feed->get_item(0);
$fore = $weather->get_forecasts();
$unit = $weather->get_units_temp();
$ampm = "n"; // indica noche
$icon = $weather->get_condition_code();
// Calculamos la hora de Mallorca en minutos
$curday = time2minuts(date("g:i a"));
//echo $curday.'---'.date('h:m d.m.y').'---'.date("g:i a");
$iniday = time2minuts($weather->get_sunrise());
$endday = time2minuts($weather->get_sunset());

if ($curday > $iniday && $curday < $endday) {
    $ampm = "d"; // indica dia
} 

$land = $weather->get_country();
if($land == 'Spain')
{
    $land = 'Spanien';
}
?>

<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Yahoo Weather</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    <!--
    body {
        font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Tahoma, Verdana;
        font-size: 12px;
        font-weight: normal;
        color: #777777;
        text-decoration: none;
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
    }
    #weather {
        width: 240px;
        height: 120px;
        margin-left: 10px;
    }
    #current {
        width: 240px;
        height: 120px;
        text-align: right;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    #current #temp {
        font-size: 24px;
        font-style: normal;
        padding-top: 40px;
        padding-right: 16px;
    }
    #current #fore {
        padding-right: 16px;
        font-size: 11px;
    }
    #current #city {
        padding-right: 16px;
    }
    -->
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="weather" style="background:url('icon<?php echo $ampm; ?>.png') no-repeat 40px 40px;">
        <div id="current" style="background:url('http://l.yimg.com/us.yimg.com/i/us/nws/weather/gr/<?php echo $icon . $ampm . ".png"; ?>') no-repeat 0px -10px;">
            <div id="temp"><?php echo $weather->get_temperature(); ?>&deg;<?php echo $unit; ?></div>
            <div id="fore"><?php echo $fore[0]->get_low() . "&deg;" . $unit; ?>
                bis <?php echo $fore[0]->get_high() . "&deg;" . $unit; ?></div>
            <div id="city"><?php echo 'Mallorca' . ", " . $land; ?></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I think it has do do something with my new server.

Cheers,

mallmis

Comment: Hi,it is working now, I just uploadet it again and it was running. Maybe problem with migration. Sorry for your time. Saludos, mallmis